# NameError : name 'ip' is not defined

Tags: networking, scapy

after installing scapy in windows when I run the "scapy" command from command line to check if scapy is installed succesfully 
it gives the following lines:

```
welcome to Scapy(2.1.1-dev) 
>>>ip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ip' is not defined
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: what do you expect it to output? Before you can expect anything usefil, you should look at http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html#quick-demo

Comment: the output is to poison the cache of vulnerable dns            please check the following link <http://downloads.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities/exploits/30131.py>                                                                when m trying to execute this code from command line the following error occurs:                                   C:\Python25>attack.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\attack.py", line 23, in <module>
UDP(sport=53, dport=dnsport)/ \
NameError: name 'IP' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Try.. doing this .. this would create a IP object and print it

```
>>>> print IP()
```

Or else populating IP options is explained in detail here: http://allievi.sssup.it/techblog/?p=631

```
>>> ip=IP(src="1.1.1.1", dst="8.8.8.8", options=IPOption('\x83\x03\x10'))
```